# how to merge and attach pdf to record using conga composer with out user interference?

Tags: conga

I have a button on click it opens a new window with conga composer and I have to select a template and have to select merge option but my requirement is on click a pdf is attached to the record automatically

Comment: I would suggest speaking to Conga support (which is excellent)

Answer (score 1):

Pavan,
You can achieve this with background mode (&DS7=1). You'll first need to define the template with &TemplateID= [ID of the desired template] in your button.

Here's some more information on best practices for using background mode. [Parameter Deep Dive: Background Mode Using DS7](http://www.congamerge.com/blog/latest-posts/october-2013/parameter-deep-dive-background-mode-using-ds7)

If you have any trouble give us a shout at support@congamerge.com.

Hayley